# Uploading data stream from an Android device (app) to a remote http server

Tags: android, json, node.js, http, server

I am working on an app that extracts vehicle data (array of JSON objects) and display them on the dashboard of my Android screen. The issue is : how to upload these data to a remote HTTP server to use them later on. The app presents a field called Target URL . But when I just fill it by an IP address , nothing happens . I think I should have an intermediate app to intake data from the initial android app.

### Edit

The application (called OpenXC Enabler) is using a public class called UploaderSink which uploads a stream of all incoming vehicle data to a remote HTTP server. 
The remote HTTP server specified should be expecting POST requests with the data being a JSON array of OpenXC JSON message objects, e.g.:

```
[
    {
        "name": "steering_wheel_angle",
        "value": 42
    }, 
    {
        "name": "parking_brake_status", 
        "value": false
    }
]
```

My question is **HOW TO CREATE THIS HTTP SERVER TO GET THE DATA**. I tried a simple code (post request) with node js,but nothing.I followed a tutorial on bluemix, but it's more complicated to visualize data through the IoT Foundation.

Comment: You should consider adding more information, have you tried anything ? You should also read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Maybe provide some code aswell, it will really help us help you.

Comment: The application (called OpenXC Enabler) is using a public class called UploaderSink which uploads a stream of all incoming vehicle data to a remote HTTP server. The remote HTTP server specified should be expecting POST requests with the data being a JSON array of OpenXC JSON message objects, e.g.: [{"name": "steering_wheel_angle", "value": 42}, {"name": "parking_brake_status", "value": false}]

Comment: You should not use comments to explain what you want. You are expected to put all info in your post. Write a decent story!

Comment: greenapps, it was to answer Nicolas. The decent story is already there

Answer (score 0):

I use OkHTTP http://square.github.io/okhttp/ and REST API https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer for that

And org.json to parse and compose JSON strings